# How to get an element above $ionicBackdrop?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

It seems a very z-index issue, but I am not able to get a solution.
I am trying to get an element in ion-view to come above `$ionicBackdrop`.

Example Pen: http://codepen.io/ankitjain11/pen/grwZav

**JS:**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])

  .controller('IonicBackdropCtrl', function($scope, $ionicBackdrop, $timeout) {

  $scope.show = function() {
    $scope.back = true;
    $ionicBackdrop.retain();
  };
  $scope.hide = function () {
        $scope.back = false;
    $ionicBackdrop.release();
  }

});
```

**HTML:**

```
  <body ng-controller="IonicBackdropCtrl">
    <ion-view>
      <ion-content>
        <button class="button" ng-click="show()">
          Show Backdrop
        </button>
        <button class="button" ng-click="hide()" ng-show="back">
          Hide Backdrop
        </button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </body>
```

Here, the `Hide Backdrop` button, would come over the backdrop. Once, the backdrop is visible.

Though, my implementation is not as straight forward as the Pen, but still would serve my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/backdrop-example/15863/12) a discussion about same problem. And there is workaround for what you want as described in this discussion. Make the buttons direct child of `body` and then `z-index` changing would work. Look here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKNvrZ

Comment: any other solution when making buttons direct child of body is not an option? ):

Comment: Sorry, I don't know other solution.