# how to make ion-popover's event element, above it's ion-backdrop for coach guide?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, popover, backdrop

I'm trying to make a coach guide in my ionic app, using ion-popover. I don't want the event element (the element that is being explained by the coach text) to be in the dark area (the backdrop), but I want a specific styled backdrop on other elements. And I thought that might be a very normal thing to do UI-wise, but surprisingly I couldn't find any simple way to do it.

I tried giving higher `z-index`, but the `ion-backdrop` is out of `ion-app` and the z-index of a lower element cannot have any effect. it has been suggested in [a forum post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/backdrop-example/15863/12) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989197/how-to-get-an-element-above-ionicbackdrop) to make the element a direct child of the body, but I'm not sure if that's a right thing to do and also I'm not sure how to do it properly. Now The suggestion is old and for former versions of ionic. I was wondering whether there is a solution for this now (I am using Ionic 6, angular 14), or maybe another way to have a coach-guide that doesn't leave the element in the shadow.

Comment: You can easilly use @angular/cdk/overlay to make your own elements